# Utilize the following properties of function f(x) to answer each part

Tags: algebra-precalculus

- domain of $f(x)$ is $[-15,20]$
- $f(-5)=-10$
- $f(8)=15$
- $f(20)=50$
- $f$ is increasing on $10<x<20$
- $f$ is constant on $[5,10]$
- $f$ has zeros at $x=-10$ and $x=0$
- $f$ has an absolute minimum at $x=-5$ and an absolute maximum at $x=20$

A: evaluate $f(9)$
B: determine range of $f(x)$
C: determine average rate of change of $f(x)$ on $-10<x<-5$
D: which value is bigger: $f(-8)$ or $f(15)$?

Comment: Any ideas for yourself?

Comment: Do you know if $f$ is a continuous function?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

A.  $f$ is constant on $[5,10]$.

B.  $f$ has an absolute minimum at $x=-5$ and an absolute maximum at $x=20$

C.  Quotient of $f(-5)-f(-10)$ and $-5-(-10)$

D.  **(Edited)** Compare $f(-8)$ and $f(15)$, from the properties stated. You don't need an explicit formula.

---

**Added:**

$\color{red}{D}$. If also $f$ is continuous and the only zeros of $f$ occurs at $x=-10$ and $x=0$ we have that $f(x)< 0 $ for $-10<x<0$, then $f(-8)<0$; and $f(15)>f(10)$ since $f$ is increasing on $10<x<10$, and $f(10)=15$ cause $f$ is constant on $[5,10]$. Finally
$$f(15)>f(10)=15>0>f(-8).$$

Comment: For a and d how do I go about finding the formula so I can answer them?

Comment: In both cases $a$) and $b$) a formula is not needed. It is about of understanding how the function behaves.

Comment: I'm still super lost. Could you explain it further?

Comment: For $a$), you know that $f$ is constant on $[5,10]$, which means that $f(x)$ takes the same value for $all\, x$ on $[5,10]$. Also you know $f(8)$, can you catch it?

Comment: So then f(9) would be equal to 15?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now, for $d$) we need some aditional assumptions. Do you know if $f$ is continuous? Are $x=-10$ and $x=0$ the only zeros of $f$?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell this is correct but it is what I could think of right now...it may be helpful anyway!

**A-Evaluate $f(9)$**

Since $f$ is constant on $[5,10]$ and $f(8)=15$

Then $f(9)=15$

**B-Determine the range of $f$**

Since $f$ has an absolute minimum at $x=-5$ and an absolute maximum at $x=20$

The range is $[f(-5), f(20)] = [-10, 50]$

**C: determine average rate of change of $f(x)$ on $-10<x<-5$**

$f(-5)=-10 and f(-10)=0$

Similar to calculating the slope of a line passing through $(-5,-10)$ and $(-10,0)$, you can calculate rate of change between the 2 points as: $(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)=(0+10)/(-10+5)=10/-5=-2$

**D: which value is bigger: $f(-8)$ or $f(15)$?**

Since $f(-10)=0$ and $f(-5)=-10$ the function is increasing in this interval and $f(-8)$ would be between $0, -10$. On the contrary, $f(15)$ lies on the interval where $f$ is increasing and that interval starts at $f(10)=15$ and ends at $f(20)=50$, so $f(15)$ must be larger than $f(-8)$.

A picture may help (if correct of course!)

[image]